# Как выявить изображение без изображения / Image BLANK_DETECTED

Tags: php, изображения

Сайт на PHP. Cуществует необходимость сохранять скриншоты сторонних сайтов. В связи с тем, что Google PageSpeed Insights заблокировала API(v2), а API(v5) не дает возможность корректно распарсить изображение (или у меня не получилось, может кто-то подскажет решение - реальный пример кода для Google PageSpeed Insights API(v5) ?), пришлось искать альтернативу.
Скриншотных сервисов масса, но наметилась общая проблема: некоторые сайты, скорей всего, программно запрещают создание скриншотов (у Google PageSpeed этой проблемы не было), в результате чего сохраняется просто белый экран (скриншот без изображения), **вопрос: каким образом можно выявить такие изображения (изображения без фактического изображения)?**

Интересуют простые эффективные решения, может кто-то уже сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой или нашел способ чем заменить  Google PageSpeed Insights API(v5) для создания скриншотов?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=php%20Image%20BLANK%20DETECT&lr=219&clid=2261453&win=280

Comment: Гуглить - полезное умение, радует, что вы с такой легкостью им делитесь...

Comment: А если серьёзно: `imagecreate()` - возвращает идентификатор изображения, представляющего из себя пустое **изображение заданного размера** - но я не знаю размер (размер изображений не фиксирован)

Comment: `imagecreatetruecolor()` - возвращает идентификатор изображения, представляющий **черное изображение заданного размера** - тоже не мой случай

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте  стандатное отклонение картинки на равенство нулю. Imagick::getImageChannelStatistics